# Expand Raid 5 Array on a HP ML350 G6 with ESXi 4.0 and P410i Controller

Tags: raid, vmware-esxi

I have to increas an Raid 5 Array 270GB (3x 146GB SAS) with an additional 146GB SAS hard disk.

On the Server runs a Vmware ESXI 4.0 with two Win 2008 Virtual Machines.
The Server (HP Proliant ML350 G6) has a Smart Array Controller P410i with Firmware 1.62.

Can I simple expand the raid 5 Array with the HP SmartCD and the program HP Array Configuration Utility (ACU).? 
Is anything else to do after rebooting?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely.  Just pop in the HP SmartCD and walk through the RAID setup.  If the disk is found, you simply add it into the existing array....reboot....done!